# Insertar despus de una Form-Group

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3

El siguiente codigo hace que mi elemento nuevo se inserte despues del elemento input:

```
.validate({ errorPlacement: function (error, element) { element.after(error); },
```

Es decir, tengo este codigo HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-label" placeholder="" />
  <label for="email-label">Your Email</label>
</fieldset>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
  }
  
  fieldset.form-group {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  label {
    position: absolute;
    top: .6rem;
    left: 1rem;
    transition: all .4s linear;
  }
  
   :focus+label {
    color: #800040;
    top: -15px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
  }
</style>
```

Si ese campo lo dejo vacio, se me agrega un label despues del input:

`<label id="confirm-error" class="error" for="confirm">Este campo es requerido.</label>`

Quedando el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-label" placeholder="" />
  <label id="confirm-error" class="error" for="confirm" style="color:red">Este campo es requerido.</label>
  <label for="email-label">Your Email</label>
</fieldset>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
  }
  
  fieldset.form-group {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  label {
    position: absolute;
    top: .6rem;
    left: 1rem;
    transition: all .4s linear;
  }
  
   :focus+label {
    color: #800040;
    top: -15px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
  }
</style>
```

Y lo que quiero es que quede debajo, asi:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-label" placeholder="" />
  <label for="email-label">Your Email</label>
</fieldset>
 <label id="confirm-error" class="error" for="confirm" style="color:red; padding-top:80px; padding-left:30px">Este campo es requerido.</label>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
  }
  
  fieldset.form-group {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  label {
    position: absolute;
    top: .6rem;
    left: 1rem;
    transition: all .4s linear;
  }
  
   :focus+label {
    color: #800040;
    top: -15px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
  }
</style>
```

Entonces como digo en el primer codigo que adjunte que enlugar de que sea despues del Input, sea despues del Form-Group, es decir despues de `</fieldset>`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a buscar al tag padre del input:

```
.validate({ errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    element.parent().after(error);
}, ...
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, era lo que buscaba, ahora te pregunto spor si sabes, como puedo agregarle propiedades como el padding-top?